# Mavericks Firefox stops emitting timed socket.io events regularly

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox, socket.io, osx-mavericks

I have a local node.js server that simply logs socket.io events to the console.

On the client side, I'm using setInterval() to set up a socket.io event to be emitted to the server every two seconds.

Here's the server side code:

```
var handler = function(req, res) {
 fs.readFile('./page.html', function (err, data) {
   if(err) throw err;
   res.writeHead(200);
   res.end(data);
 });
}

// Include dependencies, set up the server and make it listen to the port.
var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
var fs = require('fs');
var port = 3250;
app.listen(port);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
 socket.on("foo", function() {
   var now = new Date();
   console.log('got foo at ' + now.getSeconds());
 });
});
```

..and the client:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Idle bug test</title>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
 socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3250');
 window.setInterval("socket.emit('foo');", 2000);
 //window.setInterval("socket.emit('foo');console.log(Date.now());", 2000);
}
</script>
</head><body></body>
</html>
```

To reproduce the bug:

- Use OS X Mavericks (does not seem to happen with Mountain Lion)
- Start the server in a terminal with "node index.js"
- Start Firefox (27.0.1) and go to localhost:3250
- Don't open the Firefox console.
- Focus on the terminal
- Wait for "about a minute, sometimes less, sometimes more"

Result:

```
$ node index.js
  info  - socket.io started
  debug - served static content /socket.io.js
  debug - client authorized
  info  - handshake authorized t9vjvs20j61l5gcuH52s
  debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/t9vjvs20j61l5gcuH52s
  debug - set heartbeat interval for client t9vjvs20j61l5gcuH52s
  debug - client authorized for
  debug - websocket writing 1::
got foo at 34
got foo at 36
got foo at 38
got foo at 40
got foo at 42
got foo at 44
got foo at 46
got foo at 48
got foo at 50
got foo at 52
got foo at 54
got foo at 56
  debug - emitting heartbeat for client t9vjvs20j61l5gcuH52s
  debug - websocket writing 2::
  debug - set heartbeat timeout for client t9vjvs20j61l5gcuH52s
  debug - got heartbeat packet
  debug - cleared heartbeat timeout for client t9vjvs20j61l5gcuH52s
  debug - set heartbeat interval for client t9vjvs20j61l5gcuH52s
got foo at 58
got foo at 0
got foo at 2
got foo at 4
got foo at 6
got foo at 8
got foo at 10
got foo at 22 # WTF?
got foo at 22
  debug - emitting heartbeat for client t9vjvs20j61l5gcuH52s
  debug - websocket writing 2::
  debug - set heartbeat timeout for client t9vjvs20j61l5gcuH52s
  debug - got heartbeat packet
  debug - cleared heartbeat timeout for client t9vjvs20j61l5gcuH52s
  debug - set heartbeat interval for client t9vjvs20j61l5gcuH52s
got foo at 33
got foo at 33
got foo at 45
got foo at 45
  debug - emitting heartbeat for client t9vjvs20j61l5gcuH52s
  debug - websocket writing 2::
  debug - set heartbeat timeout for client t9vjvs20j61l5gcuH52s
  debug - got heartbeat packet
  debug - cleared heartbeat timeout for client t9vjvs20j61l5gcuH52s
  debug - set heartbeat interval for client t9vjvs20j61l5gcuH52s
got foo at 47
got foo at 59
got foo at 59
got foo at 1 # Brought focus back on Firefox, things back to normal
  debug - client authorized
  info  - handshake authorized aqvmz-zNImkzF0zPH52t
  debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/aqvmz-zNImkzF0zPH52t
  debug - set heartbeat interval for client aqvmz-zNImkzF0zPH52t
  debug - client authorized for
  debug - websocket writing 1::
got foo at 3
got foo at 5
got foo at 7
got foo at 9
got foo at 11
  debug - emitting heartbeat for client t9vjvs20j61l5gcuH52s
  debug - websocket writing 2::
  debug - set heartbeat timeout for client t9vjvs20j61l5gcuH52s
  debug - got heartbeat packet
  debug - cleared heartbeat timeout for client t9vjvs20j61l5gcuH52s
  debug - set heartbeat interval for client t9vjvs20j61l5gcuH52s
got foo at 13
got foo at 15
got foo at 17
^C$
```

At the point marked with "WTF", Firefox starts taking breaks, and emitting events in double.

To reproduce a different bug:

- Switch to using the client side line of code that logs to the console in addition to emitting the event.
- Use OS X Mavericks (does not seem to happen with Mountain Lion)
- Start the server in a terminal "node index.js"
- Start Firefox (27.0.1) and go to localhost:3250
- Open the Firefox console.
- Focus on the terminal
- Wait for "something like more than a minute"

Result: Firefox goes crazy with emitting socket.io events, while logging to browser console with the console open. Or the server starts seeing events that weren't sent. There was only 1 event emitted every 2 seconds in Firefox's console.

```
$ node index.js
  info  - socket.io started
  debug - served static content /socket.io.js
  debug - client authorized
  info  - handshake authorized iBFAUZOa7BHwJYYtNNLA
  debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/iBFAUZOa7BHwJYYtNNLA
  debug - set heartbeat interval for client iBFAUZOa7BHwJYYtNNLA
  debug - client authorized for
  debug - websocket writing 1::
got foo at 42
got foo at 44
got foo at 46
got foo at 48
got foo at 50
got foo at 52
got foo at 54
got foo at 56
got foo at 58
got foo at 0
got foo at 2
got foo at 4
  debug - emitting heartbeat for client iBFAUZOa7BHwJYYtNNLA
  debug - websocket writing 2::
  debug - set heartbeat timeout for client iBFAUZOa7BHwJYYtNNLA
  debug - got heartbeat packet
  debug - cleared heartbeat timeout for client iBFAUZOa7BHwJYYtNNLA
  debug - set heartbeat interval for client iBFAUZOa7BHwJYYtNNLA
got foo at 6
got foo at 8
got foo at 10
got foo at 12
got foo at 14
got foo at 16
got foo at 18
got foo at 20
got foo at 22
got foo at 24
got foo at 26
got foo at 28
got foo at 30
  debug - emitting heartbeat for client iBFAUZOa7BHwJYYtNNLA
  debug - websocket writing 2::
  debug - set heartbeat timeout for client iBFAUZOa7BHwJYYtNNLA
  debug - got heartbeat packet
  debug - cleared heartbeat timeout for client iBFAUZOa7BHwJYYtNNLA
  debug - set heartbeat interval for client iBFAUZOa7BHwJYYtNNLA
got foo at 32
got foo at 34
got foo at 36
got foo at 38
got foo at 40
got foo at 42
got foo at 44
got foo at 46
got foo at 48
got foo at 50
got foo at 52
got foo at 54
  debug - emitting heartbeat for client iBFAUZOa7BHwJYYtNNLA
  debug - websocket writing 2::
  debug - set heartbeat timeout for client iBFAUZOa7BHwJYYtNNLA
  debug - got heartbeat packet
  debug - cleared heartbeat timeout for client iBFAUZOa7BHwJYYtNNLA
  debug - set heartbeat interval for client iBFAUZOa7BHwJYYtNNLA
got foo at 56
got foo at 58
got foo at 0
got foo at 2
got foo at 4
got foo at 6
got foo at 8
got foo at 10
got foo at 12
got foo at 14
got foo at 16
got foo at 18
got foo at 20
  debug - emitting heartbeat for client iBFAUZOa7BHwJYYtNNLA
  debug - websocket writing 2::
  debug - set heartbeat timeout for client iBFAUZOa7BHwJYYtNNLA
  debug - got heartbeat packet
  debug - cleared heartbeat timeout for client iBFAUZOa7BHwJYYtNNLA
  debug - set heartbeat interval for client iBFAUZOa7BHwJYYtNNLA
  debug - client authorized
  info  - handshake authorized RjQh8QPYaxxxJbiONNLB
  debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/RjQh8QPYaxxxJbiONNLB
  debug - set heartbeat interval for client RjQh8QPYaxxxJbiONNLB
  debug - client authorized for
  debug - websocket writing 1::
got foo at 20
# WTF? Snipped 126 lines of "got foo at 20"
got foo at 20
got foo at 21
got foo at 21
# WTF? Snipped 124 lines of "got foo at 21"
# Focused on Firefox
got foo at 21
got foo at 22
got foo at 22
got foo at 24
got foo at 24
got foo at 26
got foo at 26
got foo at 28
got foo at 28
got foo at 30
got foo at 30
got foo at 32
got foo at 32
got foo at 34
got foo at 34
got foo at 36
got foo at 36
got foo at 38
got foo at 38
^C$
```

Any ideas what might be causing this?